# Adding custom component in xml error

Tags: android

I'm trying to create simple custom component that draws Bitmap. It works fine when I'm adding it programatically.

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.linlay); Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
               R.drawable.girl);

AdView ad = new AdView(this,mBitmap);

layout.addView(ad);
```

But when I try to add it through xml file I get error:

```
<test.com.ad.AdView
   android:id="@+id/ad"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
   ></test.com.ad.AdView>
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   test.com.ad.AdView.onMeasure(AdView.java:81)  at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:10577)    at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
>     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
>     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:10577)   at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4270)
>     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:267)   at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:10577)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4270)
>     at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1284)
>     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:613)
>     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:519)     at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:10577)    at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4270)
>     at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1284)
>     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:613)
>     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:519)     at
>   android.view.View.measure(View.java:10577)    at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.measureView(RenderSessionImpl.java:551)
>     at
>   com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:453)
>     at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:323)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:380)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1310)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1075)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:901)
>     at
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.pageChange(LayoutEditor.java:403)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:290)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4125)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1457)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1480)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1465)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1270)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:2745)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1432)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:257)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4125)     at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1457)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1480)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1465)    at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1270)  at
>   org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3971)
>     at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3610)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
>     at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)   at
>   org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)

My onMeasure looks like that:

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        setMeasuredDimension(resolveSize(bitmap.getWidth(), widthMeasureSpec),
                resolveSize(bitmap.getHeight(), heightMeasureSpec));

    }
```

What is wrong here ?

Comment: what is the value of bitmap? it is not getting bitmap and hence NPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `new AdView(this,mBitmap);` at coding then you passing `mBitmap` but when you try to add it through xml then mBitmap is null becuase you didnt pass mBitmap.. so you must change your `AdView(this)` instead of `AdView(this,mBitmap);` and add 
`Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.girl);` 
in `AdView()` class